# How to use user stories in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-workitem, user-stories

I am using TFS 2012/VS 2012.

I have five work items available to me: Bug, PBI, Task, Test Case and Impediment. I cannot figure out how to access user stories, and none of the information put out by Microsoft is very helpful.

I suspect the template that was used to create my project did not include them, but I am not sure. Is this true?

Can I alter my existing project to add user stories or requirements?

When creating a new project, which templates will automatically contain user stories or requirements?

Comment: PBIs are the requirement type for the template you're using. That's a _Product Backlog Item_.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you used the Scrum Template to create your Team Project.  Only the Agile Template includes User Stories by default.

You can use the witadmin.exe tool to add additional Work Item Types to an existing project.

In Scrum PBI is the equivalent of a User Story (and in CMMI the Requirement is the equivalent of a User Story).